# Missing Geocode search result

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have the following problem on my own site using Mapbox, but I'll use Mapbox's own webpages to explain what I'm facing as I see the same issue there.
I use Mapbox's Geocoder example at this link: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mapbox-gl-geocoder and I search for 'Feriekompagniet' and nothing shows up.
I then click the 'Improve this map' link in the bottom right corner of the map - this takes me to this site: [Improve map](https://www.mapbox.com/contribute/#/?owner=mapbox&id=streets-v11&access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiZXhhbXBsZXMiLCJhIjoiY2p0MG01MXRqMW45cjQzb2R6b2ptc3J4MSJ9.zA2W0IkI0c6KaAhJfk9bWg&utm_source=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.mapbox.com%2F&utm_medium=attribution_link&utm_campaign=referrer&l=15.3524%2F55.5537%2F8.1244&q=)
I do the same search for 'Feriekompagniet' and it finds what I'm looking for (Feriekompagniet A/S).
Can anyone tell me what the difference is - how can I get the same search results as on the 'Improve this map' site?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I'm getting the same thing.  75% of the searches I've performed that are showing on Mapbox maps (e.g. Contribute or the Geocoder playground) do not appear in the Geocoder address/POI results, which are very poor.  I submitted a support request, maybe do the same?

Comment: Check out https://github.com/mapbox/carmen/issues/696 - from 4 years ago.  :/

Comment: @manafire allthough I agree with what you write, my questions is more 'how do they do it?' in the 'improve map' site where the search results indeed do show up - how do I get the same search results on my own page?